# Why is the best time complexity of the sorting problemo O(nlog(n)) when radix sort is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In my textbook, I am told that the sorting problem has a time complexity of  `θ(n*log(n))`. However, it is simple to show that Radix sort is `O(n)`. Doesn't this contradict what is said? Isn't the lower bound time complexity for sorting problem thus `θ(n)`?

Edit: StackOverflow won't let me put "problem" in my title so "problemo" has to stay.

Comment: You need to consider the best time, worst time and average time scenarios.

Comment: The detailed answer is available under Efficiency paragraph here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? Just trying to understand why the lower bound is what it is when I can demonstrate an algorithm that has a better time complexity.

Comment: @Axalix can you explain why `w` must be at least `log(n)`?

Comment: Because there has to be a unique address-value for each of the `n` inputs.  That's a word-size (w) of at least `log(n)` bits.  This is where the "radix" of radix-sorting comes from.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you, @RBarryYoung

Comment: @RBarryYoung, that is true only for distinct elements.

Comment: @KennethWorden, There is always a counting sort with `O(n+k)` complexity.

Comment: @KennethWorden that lemma says: `No` **Comparison** based sorting algorithm can sort an array in less than NlogN compares. So this is for comparison based algorithms, Does radix sort compare things? No

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ω(n*log(n))` is a lower bound for a [comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), not any existing sorting algorithm. Radix sort is not a comparison sort.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, the time complexity is O (mn), but it can be approximated as O (n) ，when m is much smaller than n, and it is not strictly wrong to say that there is no ordering of O (n).